# Problem with returning an array to a function in C

Tags: c, scope, return-value, c-strings, storage-duration

My problem is that I can't return the processed string to the function. The function's job is that it must accept a string, change its letters, and return the processed string to the function.

```
char *dna_strand(const char *dna)
{
    int a;
   for (a = 1; *(dna+a) != '\0' ; a++) {
}
 char array[a];
    for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        if ('A' == *(dna + i)) {
            array[i] = 'T';
        } else if ('T' == *(dna + i)){ 
            array[i] = 'A';
        } else{
            array[i] = *(dna + i);
        }
    }
      return array;
}
```

Error :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwvCh.png

Comment: Please post error message as text instead of image.  Format the code so it's not misleading.  Use `strlen() + 1` instead of the first loop.

Comment: `VLA` is an `C99` extension and shall be avoided. Better use `alloca` instead of `array[i]` or in your case, `malloc` then return the allocated string, but then you must free it.

Comment: @IlianZapryanov `alloca` would not work as op wants to return the value.

Comment: you are promising a string but an array is not null terminated

Comment: The function doesn't return an array. It returns a pointer to an array. Then the array is destroyed. Then the function which calls this function tries to use the array.

Answer (score 2):

The local variable `char array[a];` is out of scope for caller so you cannot use that to return a value.  Instead allocate memory on the heap with `malloc()` or  as here`strdup()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *dna_strand(const char *dna) {
    char *array = strdup(dna);
    if (!array) return array;
    for (int i = 0; array[i]; i++) {
        if (dna[i] == 'A') array[i] = 'T';
        else if (dna[i] == 'T') array[i] = 'A';
    }
    return array;
}

int main() {
    char *s = dna_strand("ATTCG");
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to be fancy use `strpbrk()` to find the next letter we need to map instead of stepping one letter at a time:

```
char *dna_strand(const char *dna) {
    char *array = strdup(dna);
    for (char *p = array; p; p = strpbrk(p, "AT")) {
        if (*p == 'A') *p++ = 'T';
        else *p++ = 'A';
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Scope is not the applicable concept here. Objects may be used in code outside the scope of their identifiers. The appropriate concepts are storage duration and lifetime; objects may not be used after their lifetimes end.

Answer (score 1):

You may not return a pointer to a local array with automatic storage duration because after exiting the function the array will not be alive and the returned pointer will be invalid.

You need to allocate an array dynamically.

Pay attention to that this loop

```
for (a = 1; *(dna+a) != '\0' ; a++) {
```

can invoke undefined behavior when the user will pass to the function an empty string.

You should write at least like

```
int a = 0;
while ( *(dna+a) != '\0' ) ++a;
++a;
```

or

```
int a = 0;
do ; while ( *( dna + a++ ) != '\0' );
```

After that you can allocate dynamically a character array

```
char *array = malloc( a );
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a pointer to a local variable's address, because it will be destroyed when it will goes out from the function's scope.

Since, `a` is not a constant value, you cannot initialize `array` as `static`.
Hence, the only option is left is using *heap-allocation*.

`a` can be initialize like this:

```c
char *array = calloc(a + 1, sizeof(char));
```

*Note: `calloc()` is defined in `stdlib.h` header file.*

Comment: sizeof(char) is defined as 1

Comment: Wording is not accurate: _You cannot return a local variable_ -> _You cannot return a **pointer** to a local variable_

Comment: @AllanWind: `sizeof (char)` is indeed 1 by definition although it is not defined to be 1. (The fact that `sizeof (char)` evaluates to 1 is a logical conclusion of the definitions of `sizeof` and `char`, but it is not the explicit definition of `sizeof (char)`.) However, it is not good advice to suggest it not be used, as your comment perhaps implies. If `char` is explicitly called out where the code relies in it, this helps both to communicate to readers what the code is doing and to make it easier to update for future changes…

Comment: … For example, if somebody wishes to migrate character-handling code to wide-character-handling code, the fact the original other explicitly used `char` in `sizeof` and other places makes it easier for the migrator to find them and replace them with `wchar_t`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if you make such a change, you need to port your code.  As op used the type the would have to change sizeof(char) to sizeof(new_type).  To your point, they should use the variable name instead (*array).

Comment: I have never seen `wchar` in the wild, btw, but I would say the most likely change is utf8 these days.  With utf8 the proposed change  would not buy you anything anyways as it would still use `char` (only the iterator step `++i` in ops original code would have be be more involved to find each variable sized character).  sizeof(char) is explicitly defined as 1 (6.5.3.4 section 4) so it's equally correct to write `sizeof(char)` or `1`.  This code appears to be for a class and will never see changed requirements.